# My Set does not add any element when I do a plus on it

Tags: android, list, kotlin, set

I'm making a feature that you can select multiple groups, then depending on the groups selected I need to do a query , but my problem is that I have created a Set that will store the groups id, currently the debugger just steps throught every plus and minus into the set but the set stills empty when I hit the last debug point, this is my code

```
 class GroupsAdapter(private val context: Context,private val groupList:List<Group>,val itemClickListener:OnCheckBoxClicked):BaseAdapter() {

    private var selectedGroups:Set<String> = hashSetOf()

    interface OnCheckBoxClicked{
        fun onGroupCheckBoxClick(group:Group,selectedGroups:Set<String>)
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View {
        val group = groupList[position]
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.group_spinner_layout,p2,false)

        if(position == 0){
            group.isChecked = true
            view.group_checkbox.isChecked = group.isChecked
        }
        view.txt_group_name.text = group.group_name
        view.group_checkbox.isChecked = group.isChecked

        view.group_checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, isChecked ->
            group.isChecked = isChecked

            if(group.isChecked){
                selectedGroups.plus(group.group_id)
            }else{
                selectedGroups.minus(group.group_id)
            }

            view.group_checkbox.isChecked = group.isChecked
            itemClickListener.onGroupCheckBoxClick(group,selectedGroups)
        }
        return view
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Group = groupList[position]

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long = position.toLong()

    override fun getCount(): Int = groupList.size
}
```

Then in my view I get the selected item and all the previously selected items like this

```
  override fun onGroupCheckBoxClick(group: Group,selectedGroups:Set<String>) {
            setGroupSelection(selectedGroups,group.group_id)
    }

    private fun setGroupSelection(selectedGroups: Set<String>,latestUsedGroup:String){
        messageInput.apply {
            group_ids = selectedGroups.toList()
        }
        SharedPrefsUtils.saveLatestUsedGroup(latestUsedGroup)
        viewModel.setGroupMembersInput(
            GroupMembersInput(viewModel.getCurrentOrganization.value!!,
                selectedGroups.toList())
        )
    }
```

Now, selectedGroups here returns an empty set but I was adding with plus in the adapter, I have checked it with the debugger

### Steps that the debugger does

**First**

[image]

**Second**

[image]

But then in the UI the set returns empty

[image]

Comment: From [Set.plus](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/plus.html) `Returns a set containing all elements of the original set and then the given element if it isn't already in this set.`. Plus returns a completely new Set with the element given, and does not change anything to the original set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should use `add`, `remove` instead of `plus`, `minus`

`plus`, `minus` returns a new set.

according to the [document](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/plus.html) (for `plus` operator):

> Returns a set containing all elements of the original set and then the given element if it isn't already in this set.